# Copy range from one worksheet to another based on criterion

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a range of cells to another worksheet based on the criterion given in column N.   So for each row it has to check whether or not it meets criterion in column N. If the value in Column N = `1`, it should copy from that row  `Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 8))` to another worksheet starting at row 10. If the value in Column N = `0` it skips that row and checks the next one. So it doesn't copy that row.

Maybe my wrong code can explain it better than me:

```
Sub TCoutput()
   Dim i As New Worksheet
   Dim e As New Worksheet

   Set i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet.Item(3)
   Set e = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(4)
   Dim d
   Dim j

   d = 10
   j = 3

   Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("N" & j))

       If i.Range("N" & j) = "1" Then 
         d = d + 1
           e.Range(Cells(d, 1), Cells(d, 8)) = i.Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j,8))
       End If
       j = j + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Set i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet.Item(3)`?

Comment: I do not really know, I saw that somewhere in order to activate the worksheet you're working on? Because I work with multiple worksheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. Ive add .value and d =d + 1

```
    Sub TCoutput()
       Dim i As New Worksheet
       Dim e As New Worksheet

       Set i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
       Set e = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(2)
       Dim d
       Dim j

       d = 10
       j = 3

       Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("N" & j))

           If i.Range("N" & j) = "1" Then
               e.Range(e.Cells(d, 1), e.Cells(d, 8)).Value = i.Range(i.Cells(j, 1), i.Cells(j, 8)).Value
                d = d + 1
           End If
           j = j + 1
       Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly now! Thank you so much. Finally, I can continue!

Answer (score 1):

When using multiple spreadsheets, you need to be careful and make sure all `.Range` and `.Cells` references include the worksheet you want to.  First things first, replace your `If` statement with this one:

```
If i.Range("N" & j) = "1" Then 
    e.Range(e.Cells(d, 1), e.Cells(d, 8)) = i.Range(i.Cells(j, 1), i.Cells(j,8))
End If
```

Or, you can use `With` (which I personally prefer):

```
With i
 If .Range("N" & j) = "1" Then
     e.Range(e.Cells(d,1),e.Cells(d,8)) = .Range(.Cells(j,1),.Cells(j,8))
 End If
End with
```

Without the explicit reference to a worksheet, the `Cells()` and `Range()` will defer to whichever one is the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thank u for your reaction. Still doesn't work however. Now I don't get any errors, but it still doesnt copy the range. And I forgot to add d = d + 1

Comment: I've found something that worked, but whenever I run the macro, the excelfile goed grazy because it is continouisly selecting 2 worksheets. I've put the code above aswell. So i prefer to do it with your anwer